# Работа с строками python

Tags: python

как убрать апострофы из строки: '"Просто текст"', чтобы получилось так: "Просто текст"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так:

```
"Просто текст".strip('"')
```

Answer (score 1):

Стандартная функция **str.replace**:

```
# оставить одинарные:
'""Просто текст""'.replace('""', '"')
# или убрать полностью:
'""Просто текст""'.replace('""', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
x = '"Просто текст"'
x = x.strip("'")
x = x.strip('"')
print(x)
```

Вывод:
`Просто текст`